# Should I Delete My Answer If I Now Think It's Wrong?

Tags: discussion, answers

I had posted an answer to this question: [Can a druid get out of wild shape to avoid an opportunity attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93876/can-a-druid-get-out-of-wild-shape-to-avoid-an-opportunity-attack)

Which I think was rightly refuted.

After some consideration, I considered my answer to be completely wrong and deleted it. Is it preferred to leave the answer, edit it, or delete it?

Answer (score 14):

Deleting that answer is fine, yes.

In general it's up to the writer of the answer. An answer that's left up is implicitly supported by its writer, and it is the writer is who earns (or suffers) the reputation effects of votes on it. It's fair to delete an answer you don't support anymore, especially so soon after it was submitted.

There are some exceptions — deleting many old, good answers for no good reason shouldn't be done, for an extreme example — but those are exceptions. *In general*, it's up to the writer. When it's a young post, it's even more up to the writer.

Comment: Yeah - leave an answer if you want to stand by it.  Leaving an answer that you don't stand by - I wouldn't personally do that.  But of course it's up to you.

Comment: I have sometimes left answers that I later decided were wrong, mostly as a “service” so that voters had different options to vote on, if the question looked like that would be useful. But that's an unusual situation, not necessary, and only really not-terrible when you've got a large reputation buffer to soak up the disagreeing downvotes. :)

Comment: Yeah, but I wouldn't do that for an answer I actively disagree with (except here on Meta, when explicitly seeding a poll). Just personally I only want to assign my name to something I think's right.

Comment: I wouldn't delete an answer I changed my mind about if it was highly upvoted-- that would seem wrong to do to the people who upvoted it especially if there are contrary upvoted answers, since the sudden censorship may well go unnoticed.  I might make it a CW, though, which I think would do a good job of dissociating my name from it if I was concerned about that.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer What is a CW? Please expand. Thanks

Comment: @ClearlyToughpick [Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)